# Проблема с импортом других файлов

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, python-import

У меня есть проект, в котором есть a.py и папка functions. В папке functions у меня два файла: __init__.py и b.py файл. В a.py я импортирую функцию из b.py. В свою очередь, эта функция использует другую функцию из a.py файла. 
Когда я запускаю a.py файл, у меня появляется ошибка: "NameError: name 'calc' is not defined". Что делать?

Вот пример папки с проектом:

```
./project
  └a.py
  └functions
    └__init__.py
    └b.py
```

Пример кода:

a.py:

```
def calc(a, b):
  print(a+b)
from functions.b import calculator
calculator(2, 5)
```

b.py:

```
def calculator(a,b):
  calc(a,b)
```

Comment: Импортировать в файл *b.py* эту функцию.. Но зачем? Что за бардак..

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать b более универсальным. проще сделать функцию аргументом `def calculator(a,b, func):
  func(a,b)` и `calculator(2, 5, calc)`

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в python невозможен импорт модуля из внешней директории во внутреннюю.
Интуитивно понятная конструкция вида

```
>>> from .. import a
```

Приведёт к ошибке

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Что в прямом смысле означает ошибку "попытки относительного импорта за пределами пакета верхнего уровня", где под пакетом верхнего уровня имеется в виду пакет, в котором находится текущий модуль.
Это означает, что дело не в неправильном выборе синтаксиса импорта, а именно в запрете импорта модуля уровнем выше.

---

Тщательнее структурируйте свои проекты, и вам не придётся прибегать к таким импортам (рекурсивный импорт, кстати, тоже очень плохая вещь)

Comment: `import sys;
sys.path[0:0] = ['any_dir_path'];
import filename`

Comment: @splash58 это решение, но, как ни крути, это можно назвать костылём. Стандартная архитектура Python не предполагает импорта за пределами текущей директории. Если создатели языка посчитали, что такая структура проекта неуместно, стоит пересмотреть свои предпочтения в структурировании проектов, а не искать лазейки, чтобы обойти системные ограничения. ИМХО.

Comment: дублировать  всю наработанную библиотеку заготовок в каждый проект тоже костыль :)

Comment: @splash58 если какие-то наработки используются постоянно в различных проектах, их можно поместить в `site-packages` и использовать оттуда)